# Probability that you're on a cancelled flight

Tags: probability

Let's say that I fly around four times per year, and one in every hundred flights is cancelled. What is the probability that I end up on a cancelled flight in a given year?

My intuition is that I can take the odds that all four flights aren't cancelled ($\bar p$), and subtract that from 1:

$$1 - \bar p^4 = 1 - 0.99^4 = 0.03940399 \approx 4\%$$

Is this correct, and if not, what should I have done instead?

**EDIT:**

My first version of the math assumed two flights a year and not four. Silly me :)

Comment: Why $^2$ and not $^4$?

Comment: four flights a year or two?

Comment: Fixed! Sorry for the confusion, I was thinking of pairs of round trips

Comment: Yes your working is fine